# How can I access/execute Go tools programmatically

Tags: go

I'm looking to build a tool that builds/compiles additional Go applications. Basically what I want to do is make a compiler for a DSL I'm working on. I can so far transpile my DSL into Go using [jennifer](https://github.com/dave/jennifer). However, if I want to compile this newly generated application to machine code I still need the Go toolchain installed on the executing machine.

I know the compiler is, itself, written in go. So it should in theory be possible, but after browsing around what looks like the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/compile/main.go) I still can't find the actual entry-point for the build subcommand.

Comment: These files might be of interest for you: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/work/build.go
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/work/action.go

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that `go get` will refuse to get `internal` packages.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. You are dealing with source code, resulting artifacts, etc. I'd choose a [concourse pipeline](https://concourse-ci.org) for that. Basically, you have a code resource, which gets transpiled to go code, and said go code gets compiled to one or more binaries, which in turn need to be made available.